# Unable to deploy meteor web app after upgrading from meteor 1.3.2.4 to 1.4.3.2

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

Migrated angular-meteor web app form meteor-1.3.2.4 to 1.4.3.2.
After an upgrade, I am not able to deploy it on Amazon ec2 server.

Meteor 1.4.3.2 with node 4.8.0 and npm 4.3.0.

> Not sure IS this because of node version or it's a meteor bug.

I am using Mup to deploy in ec2

Local it is running perfectly.

I need a fix as fast as possible.

Comment: I made local machine node version to 4.8.0 which is a meteor app node version, still having the same issue.

I made deployment time 3x as earlier but no luck. even though I have created a new instance and installed the same version of mongo as the meteor is using in my local machine. stall no luck.

local - node 4.8.0
local - npm - 2.15.11
meteor app -node 4.8.0
meteor - npm - 4.3.0

I am not understanding whether it's a problem of meteor or npm or node?